# How to get a sepcific columns data from excel sheet to store them in an arraylist of objects using POI in java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file with some columns like Firstname, LastName,ID etc... .
I want to get all the data of every given column and store them in an arraylist of objects. The thing is, I can not make sure that the data I am getting is belong to a sepicific column name like Firstname column or LastName or other columns. For example, now I have an excel file with this sequence ***(LastName,Firstname,ID)*** and the second excel file with different sequence ***(ID,LastName,Firstname)***. **How do I make sure that this lastname is for this firstname and ID?**
I have did some research but I couldnt get some thing simlillar at all. I would greatly appreciate if somebody can help me with it.

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcelDemo 
{
ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
String path;

public ReadExcelDemo(String path)
{

   this.path = path;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

         System.out.println("");

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly



                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cell.getAddress()); 
                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");

                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                }

            }


            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is my Student Class of the Arraylist

```
public class Student {

private String Firstname;
private String LastName;
private String Username;


public Student(String firstname, String lastName, String username) {

    this.Firstname = firstname;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Username = username;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return Firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    Firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

}
```

This is my main class

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

ReadExcelDemo re = new ReadExcelDemo( "E:/St.xlsx");
}

}
```

[This is the result of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZtXw.png)

[This an example of my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tmv5.png)

Comment: "How do I make sure that this lastname is for this firstname and ID?"

Comment: I understand your code very well you are printing each cell from the excel sheet

Comment: if you explain "to make sure" what I can help you

Comment: @gen.Strash thank you for the relpy. I mean how do a condition that make sure that this value is in the FirstName column not in Lastname, just as an example

Comment: I want to make sure that this cell belong to this column @gen.Strash

Comment: You want to have list full of student from the excel? ok I see. Let me try

Comment: Yes mate, that would be greate :) @gen.Strash

Comment: Your first line being writen when you run your program is showing the names of the column in excel right

Comment: Yes It is from excel file @gen.Strash

Comment: Do you see the names of your columns when you run your program?

Comment: Yes If you just add this line of code in the second case of switch statment

Comment: **JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cell.getStringCellValue());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the **First 3 cells** you read are the **names of the columns**.

**You can use row.getCell(columnIndex)**
Take a look at that code. It is getting the data by column:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
  row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
  if (row != null) {
    String cellValueMay = null;
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
      if (colIndex == theColIndexYouWant) {
        cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
        if (cell != null) {
          // Found column and there is value in the cell.
          cellValueMaybeNull = cell.getStringCellValue();
          break;
        }
    }

    // Do something with the cellValueMaybeNull here ...
  }
}
```